# How can I input a 0 or empty value on the prompt and don't let the action returned by this value be the same as the one returned by the cancel button?

Tags: javascript

I was making a simple calculator with JavaScript and, after I finished it, I started to look for some parts of my code which it could be improved. I had been trying to make an alert show up if the number 0 or empty was inputted in the prompt and it was working, but then I clicked the CANCEL button in the prompt and the same output happened. My question is how can I change the code below to be able to have one output for the 0 or empty value and another one for the CANCEL button?

```
const operacao = Number(
  prompt(
    `Qual a sua operação hoje? 
    1 - Soma (+)
    2 - Subtração (-)
    3 - Multiplicação (*)
    4 - Divisão (/)
    5 - Potenciação (^)
    6 - Raiz (*/)
    7 - Logaritmo natural (log)
    8 - Divisão inteira (resto) 
    `,
    ["Digite aqui!"]
  )
);
```

```
if (operacao == false) {
  if (confirm("Quer mesmo sair?") == true) {
    Window.close();
  } else {
    calculadora();
  }
} else if (operacao < 1 || operacao > 8) {
  alert("Por favor, escolha um número que retorne uma operação!");
  calculadora();
} else if (!operacao) {
  alert("Por Favor, digite um número válido!");
  calculadora();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [the prompt docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), "If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns null." The first thing you do with the result of `prompt` is coerce it into a `Number`. [`Number(null) === 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers), so when the user presses Cancel, all of the conditions are evaluated against `0`.

However, immediately coercing to `Number` is the wrong thing to do, because you are **losing information**. Once you've done so, there's no way to tell the difference between Cancel and typing `0`. Instead, we're going to remove the coersion as follows:

```js
const promptResult = prompt(
  `Qual a sua operação hoje? 
    1 - Soma (+)
    2 - Subtração (-)
    3 - Multiplicação (*)
    4 - Divisão (/)
    5 - Potenciação (^)
    6 - Raiz (*/)
    7 - Logaritmo natural (log)
    8 - Divisão inteira (resto) 
    `,
  ["Digite aqui!"]
);
```

Then, we're going to add an outer check to your conditionals:

```js
if (promptResult === null) { 
  // do whatever should happen when the user presses cancel
} else {
  const operacao = Number(promptResult);
  // the rest of your code goes here
...
```

Also, note [per the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers) that `Number("invalid number") === NaN`, so where you say `else if (!operacao)`, it's clearer (though no less correct) if you check explictly for `NaN`, i.e. `else if (operacao === NaN)`.

Comment: This isn't working. I'm putting operacao === null and the commands of this if/else block are being ignored.

Comment: I had missed that you are already coercing the result of `prompt` into a `Number`. `Number(null)` is `0`, so the first block (`operacao == false`) is evaluating to `true`. I'll edit my answer appropriately.